# Handling my fragment state if I add views dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I understand that Android will automatically handle the state of a fragment. For example, it will retain the text that was entered inside of an `EditText`.

I wish to save the state for `views` added to a `fragment` dynamically.

In order for Android to handle the state change, there must be an `id` value set to the view. I tested adding an `id` value to the dynamically added views using `ViewCompat.generateViewId()` but Android is not retaining the text entered inside these `EditText` views.

Manually saving the `fragment` state can be done in 2 ways. Using `ViewModel` or the `Bundle` that is passed to `onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

My questions are:

1. Am I right about this? Is there a way to get Android to *also* handle the state for dynamically added views during a state change (e.g. orientation)?
2. *Why?* If I am correct, why can't Android handle the state for dynamically added views - what information is the system lacking with dynamically added views that is has with views declared in `xml`?

Thanks in advance.